# How to do the BATCH insert in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, informix

I am using JPA with Hibernate persistence.
We are using JPA in the following configurations.

```
persistence-api 1.0 version
hibernate-core 3.3.2.GA version
hibernate-entitymanager 3.4.0.GA version
```

Is it possible to use Batch Insert in JPA with above configuration?

Please suggest how to do BATCH insert. We want to insert multiple rows in a single table without affecting performance of Database. Also suggest how many row insert is practically possible to use in batch?

Thanks in Anticipations

Answer (score 8):

JPA itself does not have have specific support for batch insert.
However, because you use Hibernate, take a look to: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

Comment: Are you saying that we can't do bulk insert in the plain JPA?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.