# How to get generated Identity value from a native JPA INSERT?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

In my application I'm generating an SQL-INSERT. This insert will be executed as JPA native query (Hibernate) and automatically generate a new identity value in our SQL Server.

How can I receive the generated identity value?

I want to avoid to do a second select to `@@IDENTITY`, because a second user could have inserted something in the meanwhile, leading to wrong results.
(seen in [Getting generated identifier for JPA native insert query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581990/getting-generated-identifier-for-jpa-native-insert-query) )

The code using @@IDENTITY looks like this:

```
Query statementInsert = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO x(colum1, column2) VALUES (:value1, :value2)");
// setting parameters...
statementInsert.executeUpdate();

Query statmentSelectId = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT @@IDENTITY");
int generatedId = ((BigDecimal) statmentSelectId.getSingleResult()).intValueExact();
```

I would prefer to put `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` right behind my `INSERT`-Statement (as seen in
[How to get Identity value from SQL server after insert record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213292/how-to-get-identity-value-from-sql-server-after-insert-record)). This would require some kind of "batch execution" for JPA native queries.

I'm dreaming of something like this:

```
Query statementInsertAndSelectId = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO x(colum1, column2) VALUES (:value1, :value2); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();");
// setting parameters...
// ?????????
int generatedId = ((BigDecimal) statementInsert.getSingleResult()); // not working, JPA complains about "No ResultSet"
```

Using "criteria builder" or "named query" is not possible in my project.

Comment: Can't you use a stored procedure?

Comment: Maybe you could use the OUTPUT Clause in your insert - if you are using SQLServer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are writing it back to back, you might get concurrent calls that will make the @@IDENTITY return the wrong value.

You need to use @@SCOPE_INDENTITY not to get the system wide latest value, but the latest value within your scope. 
According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

That might be tricky to get 2 statement in a batch in JPA. Batch insert might be a challenge that require environment specific or hibernate specific (over JPA) code. See [How to do the BATCH insert in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440397/how-to-do-the-batch-insert-in-jpa) and other posts regarding batch insert.

A store procedure could be a solution, but as a personal preference, I stay away from stored proc.

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827496/will-scope-identity-work-in-this-case, the @@SCOPE_IDENTITY works if it is within the same transaction... but it'd test it first!

Comment: first, it's `Scope_Identity()` and not `@@Scope_identity`. Second, what reason do you have for not using a stored procedure?

Comment: any code located in stored proc, triggers, etc is hidden code. If you work in small dev team, it does not matter so much. In a larger team, if your junior team member doesn't know that DB does some tricks behing the scene  it can lead to some major time waste. I not saying its bad, I'm saying its a personal pref.

Comment: It doesn't have to be hidden. IMO, using sql server without using it's built in tools like stored procedures etc' it's like driving a ferrary at 10 mph.